# WebForms repeater, set CSS class depends on item index

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ascx

I'm new with WebForms.
Now I'm using Repeater to display item from List collection.
The problem that I need to change css class depends on evenness of item.

My repeater code:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="not-even">
      <%# Eval("Title") %>
    </div>
  <ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And what I want:

```
<div class="not-even">
  Item 1
</div>
<div class="even">
  Item 2
</div>
<div class="even">
  Item 3
</div>
<div class="even">
  Item 4
</div>
```

How can I set CSS class depends on evennes of item using repeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator for that. Check the `ItemIndex` and set the correct class.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <div class="<%# Container.ItemIndex %2 == 1 ? "even" : "not-even" %>">
           Item  <%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 %>
        </div>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is `AlternatingItemTemplate` which is designed for exactly this.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="not-even">
      <%# Eval("Title") %>
    </div>
  <ItemTemplate>
  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <div class="even">
      <%# Eval("Title") %>
    </div>
  <AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Less obvious, but arguably simpler, is to just use CSS with `:nth-child(odd)` and `:nth-child(even)`.

For example, give the repeater a base css class

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptItems" class="items">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <div>
      <%# Eval("Title") %>
    </div>
  <ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Would result in

```css
.items :nth-child(odd)
{
  color:red;
}

.items :nth-child(even)
{
  color:blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div>
    Item 1
  </div>
  <div>
    Item 2
  </div>
  <div>
    Item 3
  </div>
  <div>
    Item 4
  </div>
</div>
```